# What is the infimum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find  $\inf_{n \in \mathbb N} (\sin(n))^2 $. I think that the answer is $0$ but I couldn't prove it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it $\sin(\sin(n))$ or $(\sin(n))^2$?

Comment: How well can you approximate $\pi$ by rational numbers?

Comment: It is $(\sin n)^2$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's really standard notation…

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Where?

Comment: @AsafKaragila He originally wrote $\sin^2n$, for which you asked clarification. It's horrible notation, I agree, but it's standard.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Stewart's calculus book, for instance: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-Strategy-Integra_Stu.pdf, top half of page 2. It was certainly the notation I learned, which - together with $\sin^{-1}=\arcsin$ - led to me losing many silly points on exams. :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila I might have misunderstood that question, then. In any case, it's certainly the notation used in any trig or calc book I've ever read. Perhaps it's not standard in Israel? (Also, I'm slightly curious if equations are read left-to-right there. Also if $\aleph_0$ is drawn in cursive.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I don't remember how I was taught in freshman year, but I do recall being confused over this notation later on, which indicates that there wasn't a consistent notation between professors over the years. (As for the additional questions: a qualified no; and a resounding no.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila They're _not_ read left-to-right? That is, they're read backwards from the way they're read over here? Interesting.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I'm not good with left/right. I might a qualified yes. They're read as normal, but it may (and it does) get confusing when the equation is interspersed text.

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem:** Let $a>0$ be irrational. Then the sequence of natural numbers is dense in $\mathbb R/(a\mathbb Z)$.

**Proof:**

*The sequence is injective:* Assume $n$ and $m$ with $n\ne m$ are equivalent in $\mathbb R/(a\mathbb Z)$. That means $n-m=az$ for a non-zero integer $z$. So $a=(n-m)/z \in\mathbb Q$. Contradiction.

Since $\mathbb R/(a\mathbb Z)$ is compact and the sequence infinite (implied by injectivity) it has a cluster point. In particular we have $n,m$ with $n<m$ which are arbitrarily close together. Let $b\in \mathbb R/(a\mathbb Z)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $n,m$ with distance less then $\varepsilon$. Then by adding multiplies of $(m-n)$ to an arbitrary element of $\mathbb R/(a\mathbb Z)$ we get into an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $b$.

**QED.**

**Answer of the question:**

Because $\pi$ is irrational the sequence of natural numbers is dense in $\mathbb R/(\pi\mathbb Z)$ (by our **Theorem**). So there is an increasing sequence of natural numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converging to the equivalence class of $0$. Since $\sin(x)^2:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is periodic of period $\pi$ it factors through $\mathbb R/(\pi\mathbb Z)$. Continuity of $\sin(x)^2$ gives you

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\sin(a_n)^2 = 0.$$

Since we have $\sin(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ we have shown
$$\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} \sin(n)^2=0.$$

Comment: I think for the OP, the part to focus on in this answer is the first sentence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Better now?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answering the question entirely, let me give a hopefully helpful suggestion:

Say you want to show that for some $n$, $\sin^2n<\epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$. Draw the unit circle! What you want to say is that for some $n$, the point "$n$ radians" lies within $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ of the $x$-axis. Essentially, it would be enough to show that if you plot the integer-radian points on the unit circle, they would basically "fill" it in some sense. Can you do this? (HINT: consider the infimum of the set of distances between integer-radian points, and use the fact that $\pi$ is irrational.)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There is a theorem that says that for any non-negative number $\alpha$, you can find arbitrarily large integers $p,q$ such that $|\alpha - p/q| \leq 1/q^2$. If you combine this with a theorem about how to compare $|\sin x|$ to $|x|$ for small $|x|$, you'll show the answer is indeed $0$ just as you thought.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already *know* that $\sin$ is continuous and $2\pi$ periodic.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in (-\delta, \delta)$ follows $|\sin(x)| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Now, by Dirichlet's approximation theorem, there exist integers $k$ and $n$ with 
$$ |2\pi k - n| < \delta. $$
Finally, by periodicity we have
$$ \sin(n)^2 = \sin(n - 2\pi k)^2 < \epsilon. $$